# /var/run/httpd.pid missing

Tags: centos, httpd, httpd.conf

Recently one of our web servers httpd stopped working and I haven't  been able to find the problem. Today I sat down and went through every directory in the httpd.conf and have found an issue.

the /var/run/httpd.pid is missing from the folder.

All other files are there and seem to be fine. I cannot create a new file with the same name in vi and I have no idea what could have caused this.

I imagine it was caused by a cold reboot at some stage as no other extraordinary processes have been run on this server at the time it went down.

I am running CentOS 3.

How can I reinstate this file?

Answer (score 1):

You have to find out where your Apache creates its PID and who is the owner of the process. Then, check if the Apache owner has the read/write access to the destination directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
service httpd restart
```

Comment: Yes.. That would be nice, unfortunately that was the first thing I did.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I found what the pid files are used for. Sorry for wasting your time.